# How can a conversion from string to char[] make it longer?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a problem I cannot really understand how it could exist.

I have a bunch of files ordered by time and containing a bunch of objects. The result should be one file per time ordered in a directory per object.

It works quite fine but at the point where I convert the `Outputstring` to a `char[]` to use `fstream.open()`, the array has 3 characters more than the string has.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string strOutput;
    char *OutputFile;
    short z;

    strOutput = "/home/.../2046001_2013-02-25T0959.txt";
    cout << strOutput << endl;

    OutputFile = new char[strOutput.length()];
    z = 0;
    while (z < strOutput.length())
    {
            OutputFile[z] = strOutput[z];
            z++;
    }

    cout << OutputFile << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first output is always correct but the second sometimes has the end `.txt60A`, `.txt5.a` or `.txt9.A`. 
When it occurs its always the same object and time and it happens every try. But not every object does that.

For obvious reasons I cannot reproduce this error in this minimal code snippet, but I also don't want to post the whole 390 lines of code.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [`strOutput.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: You're not copying the nul terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing terminating null at the end of C string. To fix:

```
OutputFile = new char[strOutput.length() + 1]; // notice +1
z = 0;
while (z < strOutput.length())
{
    OutputFile[z] = strOutput[z];
    z++;
}
OutputFile[z] = 0; // add terminating 0 byte
```

---

Of course there are better ways to do the whole thing... you don't really need to copy at all, just get rid of `OutputFile` and the whole loop, and use the char array inside `std::string`:

```
cout << strOutput.c_str() << endl;
```

I assume the real code wants a C string. `std::cout` can print `std::string` directly, of course:

```
cout << strOutput << endl;
```

---

If you actually want to create a copy, it's best to just copy `std::string` and store that, and use c_str-method to get the C buffer when you need it:

```
string OutputFile = strOutput;
```

---

If you know you really *do* need a raw char array allocated from heap, you should use `std::unique_ptr` (or possibly some other C++ smart pointer class) to wrap the pointer, so you do not need to delete manually and avoid memory leaks, and also use standard library function to do copying:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
```

...

```
unique_ptr<char[]> OutputFile(new char[strOutput.length() + 1];
::strcpy(OutputFile, strOutput.c_str()); // :: means top level namespace
```

Comment: `fs_output.open(strOutput.c_str(), ios::out| ios::binary);`Does not work.
It says there is an invalid pointer. 
But the loop works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @FThewes Strange... Remember to `delete[]` the char array then, too... Or use smart pointer, because in most "real" application C++ code you should *never* need to call `delete` (except when mandated by some older library API or something, which is very rare).

Answer (score 1):

Char arrays need an extra null character or `\0` appended to the end, otherwise the code reading the string will run past the end of the array until it finds one.

```
OutputFile = new char[strOutput.length() + 1];
z = 0;
while (z < strOutput.length())
{
    OutputFile[z] = strOutput[z];
    z++;
}
OutputFile[z] = '\0';
```

It may appear to work if the next byte after the array happens to be a null, but that's just a coincidence. I'm sure that's why your code works on the first pass.

Answer (score 0):

> > at the point where I convert the Outputstring to a char[] to use fstream.open()

You don't have to do that. Do something like this instead:

```
outfile.open(Outputstring.c_str(), std::fstream::out)
```

Of course, if you have a C++11-compliant compiler, you can just do:

```
outfile.open(Outputstring, std::fstream::out)
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I got a
`*** glibc detected *** ./test: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fbc9bc928d2 ***
`